# AngularJs Structure

Tags: angularjs

The example at http://www.teebow.net/splitting-angularjs-controllers-separate-files/ illustrates a technique for elements like CRUD. Should one use a new controller for every element? Wouldn't this end up with a ton of files like:

```
updateProductController.js
deleteProductController.js
showProductController.js
```

etc. etc.

In Laravel, one can do it like this:

```
productController@update
```

Is using a new controller for every element a normal design pattern?

Comment: Not clear at all what you are asking. You shouldn't need separate controllers for each crud task unless you have different angular routes for each task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First:** Using controllers helps separate Model / View from Controller logic and it can be argued, is one of the strengths of angular. So yes, using many controllers is, in my opinion, a way of breaking up your logic - neatly.

**Second:** The way in which you design an angular application is open to preference. But if you are not careful, you can develop [anti-patterns](https://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/software-development-antipatterns) which provide the basis for negative coding practices.

**Third:** You should reference Todd Motto's and John Papa's design and style guide [located here](https://johnpapa.net/angular-style-guide/) [and here](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide). Their observations have given a large portion of the angular community best practices and standards for developing angular applications.